# почему не работает мой код?

Tags: javascript

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не работает код. Он выдаёт NaN:

```
function sum (a, b) {
    var c = this.a + this.b;
    return console.log(c);
}

sum(3+3);
```

я пробовал и так, всё равно не получается:

```
function sum (a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    return console.log(c);
}

sum(3+3);
```

Чего я никак не пойму?

Comment: спасибо, ошибку убрал . вот так заработало: `function sum1 (a, b) {
        var c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
    console.log(sum1(3, 3));`

Answer (score 5):

Используйте второй вариант:

```
function sum (a, b) {
    var c = a + b;
    console.log(c);
    return c;
}
```

И вызывайте его так:

`sum(3, 3);`

Почему? Потому, что у вас в методе 2 параметра: `a, b`.
А вы вызываете его с одним параметром: `sum(3+3);`. 3+3 - это один параметр, перед тем, как передать его в функцию, будет произведено сложение 3+3, и будет вызвана функция в таком виде: `sum(6, null)`.

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка в передаче параметра. Исправьте на:

```
Sum(3,3)
```